# change pitch of .3gp file while playing

Tags: android-mediaplayer

In my project i have recorded sound using mediaplayer and save as .3gp file but when i want to play it using some audio effect or fast forwarding or change pitch of audio while playing. i have used mediaplayer but not working.then i used audiotrack but audiotrack takes only bytestream as input to play. i just want to play .3gp file and change pitch while playing.. i use this one below.
Help me...thanks in advance...

```
public void play() {


         File path = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                            + "/sdcard/meditest/");
         File[] f=path.listFiles();
            isPlaying=true;
            int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(outfrequency,
                    channelConfigurationout, audioEncoding);
            short[] audiodata = new short[bufferSize];

            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
                        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                                f[0])));

                audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, outfrequency,
                        channelConfigurationout, audioEncoding, bufferSize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                audioTrack.setPlaybackRate((int) (frequency*1.5));
                AudioManager audioManager =     (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                // Set the volume of played media to maximum.


                audioTrack.setStereoVolume(1.0f,1.0f);
                Log.d("Clapper","player start");
                audioTrack.play();

                while (isPlaying && dis.available() > 0) {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (dis.available() > 0 && i < audiodata.length) {
                        audiodata[i] = dis.readShort();
                        i++;
                    if(i/50==0)
                        Log.d("Clapper", "playing now"+i);
                    }
                    audioTrack.write(audiodata, 0, audiodata.length);

                }
                Log.d("Clapper","AUDIO LENGTH: "+String.valueOf(audiodata));
                dis.close();
                audioTrack.stop();


            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
            }

            Log.d("Clapper","AUDIO state: "+String.valueOf(audioTrack.getPlayState()));
            talkAnimation.stop();
            if(audioTrack.getPlayState()!=AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING)
                {


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        imgtalk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.talk1);
                    }
                });


                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried library called Sonic. Its basically for Speech as it use PSOLA algo to change pitch and tempo.
[Sonic Library](http://dev.vinux-project.org/sonic/)

Answer (score 0):

i got your problem .Media player does not support cha

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `SoundPool`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

It supports changing the pitch in realtime while playing

> The playback rate can also be changed. A playback rate of 1.0 causes the sound to play at its original frequency (resampled, if necessary, to the hardware output frequency). A playback rate of 2.0 causes the sound to play at twice its original frequency, and a playback rate of 0.5 causes it to play at half its original frequency. The playback rate range is 0.5 to 2.0.
>
> Once the sounds are loaded and play has started, the application can trigger sounds by calling SoundPool.play(). Playing streams can be paused or resumed, and the application can also alter the pitch by adjusting the playback rate in real-time for doppler or synthesis effects.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate(int, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate%28int,%20float%29)

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to change pitch while playing sound you have to use sound pool .this is the best way to do this.you can fast forward your playing by some amount and see you feel that pitch has been changed.